# I want to load array of json values from fixtures folder in an array in spec file in cypress

Tags: javascript, json, automated-tests, cypress, fixtures

Hey folks I need your help.I am working in cypress and I want to automate and validate a dropdown after every selection, right now I am using an array for it

```
 var report=  [ "Alarm","Alarm Trends","Analytics","Asset","Audit",
                "Cross Sectional Benchmarking","Degree Days",
                "Longitudinal Benchmarking"
               ]; //this array
```

But instead I want to directly load a .json file containing the array of values from fixture into the given array named report and then iterate.PS: I did try but it gave me a refernce error in it block
The code :

```
describe('Test Scenario DatePickers and Dropdowns', () => {
    before(function()  {

        cy
            .get('#addReportButton')
            .click()

            cy
            .fixture('report_types').as('report')
    })
    it('Report Type dropdown is working', function()  {
        var report=  ["Alarm","Alarm Trends","Analytics","Asset","Audit",
                       "Cross Sectional Benchmarking","Degree Days","Longitudinal Benchmarking"
                    ];
        var report_length=report.length;
        cy
            .log("Pre condition: Should have Alarm as a default value")
        cy
            .get('#selectReportType')
            .should('have.value', 'Alarm');
        
            for (let index = 0; index < report_length; index++) {
                const element = report[index];
                cy
                .get('#selectReportType')
                .select(element)
                .should('contain.text',element)
               


                
            }
        
           

            
    });
});
```

JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "reportname":["Alarm","Alarm Trends","Analytics"]
    }
    
]
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the hardcoded values with the values from the json file like this:

```js
it('Report Type dropdown is working', () => {
  cy.fixture('AllesReportType.json').then((data) => {
    const reportTypes = data[0].reportname;
    reportTypes.forEach((reportType) => {
      cy.get('#selectReportType')
        .select(reportType)
        .should('contain.text', reportType)
  })
})
```